# Django Query that gets objects based latest foreign key timestamp and orders them

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I am looking to order a queryset based on a set of objects timestamp.

Here's a simplified example:

```
Class Device(models.Model:
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Event(models.Model):
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    device = models.ForeignKey(Device)
```

I want to get the latest Event of the device so I can order a Device queryset based on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an annotation to get the most recent timestamp of an event for the device and then order by that annotated field, in descending order

```
from django.db.models import Max

Device.objects.annotate(
    most_recent=Max('event_set__timestamp')
).order_by('-most_recent')
```